# How to disable a datepicker using an "if statement" wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made an application that consists of a `datePicker` and a `comboBox`. The `comboBox`has a list of numbers ranging from 0 through to 5. When the user selects "1" I want my `datePicker` to be enabled but if the user selects anything else I want the `datePicker` to be disabled. However for some reason this code doesn't work and the `datePicker` is always disabled.

My code is as fallows

xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxNoClaims" Loaded="cbxNoClaims_Loaded" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
<DatePicker Name="dpkClaim1" Loaded="dpkClaim1_Loaded" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void cbxNoClaims_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... A List.
    List<string> claim = new List<string>();
    claim.Add("0 ");
    claim.Add("1");
    claim.Add("2");
    claim.Add("3");
    claim.Add("4");
    claim.Add("5");


    // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
    comboBox.ItemsSource = claim;
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void dpkClaim1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DatePicker datePicker = sender as DatePicker;
    if ((string)cbxNoClaims.Item== "1")
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = true;

    }
    else dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = false;

}
```

Comment: '`SelectedItem` doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the selection changed event on the combo box.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxNoClaims" SelectionChanged="cbxNoClaims_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Code:

```
private void cbxNoClaims_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cbxNoClaims.SelectedItem.ToString() == "1")
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        dpkClaim1.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need `sender` without how you wrote it. :)